# Whats the meaning of Im, Is and Ih

Tags: voltage, power, current-measurement, energy, phase

I would like to know what's the meaning for the abbreviations of Im, Is and Ih in leakage currents measurements, as it is depicted in these graphis. Could anyone help me?.
The link of the source is: [*Microstructure and Degree of Degradation of ZnO Varistors in Surge Arresters Due to Operation*](http://dx.doi.org/10.24425/123800)

Image:[image]

Comment: @HarryH That I don't understant why the currents are named Im, Is and Ih   ? What are the names for the abvreviations m,s and h.....I understand that I,is for current, but "m" "s" and ""h" and I don't understand what they stand for

Comment: @DanielPrietoLópez I suspect that if you can get hold of the document in reference [4] it will tell you. In other words, you should dig a little deeper.

Comment: I also don't understand the subscripts. As far as I know they are not referenced in the paper itself.

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry I think they could mean for : Im(maximum or peak value) Is (rms but I don't think if the s is for rms) and the Ih(harmonic value). What do you think?

Comment: @Andyaka I have found that in some countries the followwing parameters are used for measure the leakage currents. Peak, and averages values and the content of harmonic values. But the Im could eb for I maximum but the Is for...average?

Comment: I have no idea. My advice still stands: find reference [4]

Comment: @Andyaka. Yes but I can't find this document

Comment: Just guessing, can't find the paper either: \$I_{max}\$, \$I_{surge}\$, \$I_{hold}\$?

Comment: Thank you @HarryH, but for you what's the meaning of I hold?

Comment: @HarryH. I have found that the parameters in leakage currents measurements are used to be: Peak, average and harmonic. The "Im" match with "maximum and "Ih" match  match with "harmonic" but the "Is" I can't see the relation with "average" or "medium"

Comment: @HarryH Sorry I think maybe you have reason in Is is for surge current, and H ir for harmonic.... or what do you mean with Ihold?

Comment: And @HarryH I surge and I max would not be the same?

Comment: I think 'h' for 'harmonic' indeed makes more sense. About 'm' and 's' I honestly don't know, it was just a guess, as I said. But 'm' for 'max' definitely seems to make sense.

Comment: @DanielPrietoLópez - Hi, (a) I have removed obsolete comments about the paper's link, as we're getting alerts for the number of comments (long comment discussions often get moved to a chatroom). (b) Notice at the bottom of page 1 of your linked paper is the email address of the corresponding author. Try emailing them to ask your question. (c) Regarding the advice to find reference [4], and you said you can't - I think the English title of that reference in the linked paper is not its original one. The publication named in [4] is Polish and I believe its original title is too.

Comment: (continued)  (d) I *think* I found ref [4] in Polish [here](https://cybra.lodz.pl/Content/2902/PEK_nr3_2007.pdf) - see PDF page 117. Is that it? That also includes the email addresses for its authors. (e) If that information allows you to answer your own question above, please post a [self-answer](/help/self-answer) *here* (which you can also áccept) explaining the solution.